# Error:Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 during Google+ integration

Tags: android, eclipse, google-plus, google-play-services

I want to integrate Google Plus in android App in Eclipse4.4.1 by referencing [site](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). But facing very frustrating error

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

in console

> GooglePlus] Dx Uncaught translation error:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space
>       GooglePlus] Dx Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space
>       GooglePlus] Dx 2 errors; aborting
>       GooglePlus] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

when i add `google-play-services_lib` as a lib in our project

[image]

and lib

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE)).addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL)).build();
}
```

I tried many tick (like clean project, rebuild) from stackoverflow but no luck.

Please guide me.

Comment: Jump to `Android Studio`

Comment: Show the jar files you have added in your build path

Comment: Remove unnecessary jars and uncheck build automatically. Clean your project and check build automatically. Try running your project then.

Comment: @M D but sir please something tick for eclipse......

Comment: @Materazzi06 i tried but no work....

Comment: I think you should follow the `Setting up for google play services` guide carefully [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) to first set up the environment correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tick and searching i got its solution it work for me hope future visitors.

**Step 1:** Goto eclipse setup folder and find ***eclipse***(configuration setting file) named file.

**Step 2:** Edit this file like this:

you can replace

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

with

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

**Step 3:** Save  and restart your eclipse.

It fine work for me hope same for others.

Thanks